# web scraping problem using the selenium library and webdriver

Tags: web-scraping

my code returns None everytime I try to print the content of the html what seems to be the peoble here's a snippet of my code:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url  = 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/za/rustenburg/299765/weather-forecast/299765'

## Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable in the Downloads directory

chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\LEBONE\Downloads\chromedriver-win64.zip\chromedriver-win64'

## Set up the Selenium webdriver with the path to the ChromeDriver executable

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (without opening a browser window)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

## Load the webpage

driver.get(url)

## Wait for a few seconds to let the JavaScript content load

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

## Get the updated page source after JavaScript execution

html = driver.page_source

## Close the webdriver

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

rustenburg_weather_page1= soup.find('div',class_='cur-con-weather-card__body')

print(rustenburg_weather_page1)

this is what I got :

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58628/devtools/browser/faad0d39-01f6-451a-bed1-72627a3712b5
None